# RESTFullYii does not get data for PUT request

Tags: php, rest, yii, put, yii-extensions

I use [RESTFullYii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail) v1.15 from here . RESTFullYii does not get data for PUT request

I faced the problem that making PUT method the data I submit are not inside the  `doRestUpdate($id, $data)` function.

In the link above it is defined as `public function doRestUpdate($id, $data).`

So it is supposed that data are submit are in `$data` variable.

Vars `$_GET, $_POST,  $_REQUEST` don't have these data too.

I watch headers of request using firebug and see that data are sent in PUT request, but they are not in `doRestUpdate` function.

[image: Screenshot]

If there is way to fix it?

Comment: it's probably because your server is not configured to accept put requests, check this with your server administrator.